# Macro composition

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm playing with Clojure macros a bit, specifically trying a macro version of map, which I imaginatively named "mmap":

```
(defmacro mmap [f coll]
    `(vector ~@(map #(list f %) coll)))
```

Please don't delve upon the *reasons* why I may be doing this. It's just a minimal reproducible example.

It works fine as long as a collection is passed to it, but when I try to compose it with another macro, mmap slices and dices the sexp with the macro itself, not its expansion.

I would like "mmap" to work like this:

```
(mmap inc [1 2 3 4])            => [2 3 4 5]
(mmap dec (mmap inc [1 2 3 4])) => [1 2 3 4] NOPE. See the edit.
```

So the question is: is there a way to force the expansion of a macro passed as an argument to another macro? In which case, how?

Thank you for any insight!

*EDIT* I just noticed that my example doesn't make sense, passing the result of the mmap macro would be like calling:

```
(mmap inc (vector 1 2 3 4))
```

which makes no sense in this specific case, but I still want to know if it can be done somehow

*EDIT2* the use of a [1 2 3 4] array instead of a symbol, like "arg" was meant to convey that the whole thing is done at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: You could call macroexpand on `coll` to make sure macroexpansion occurs first, assuming you always have literal arguments. In case the collection is a value that is known only at runtime, you cannot apply a function on it during macroexpansion.

Comment: Yes, the whole thing is performed during macro expansion, not at runtime. Also, @coredump thank you for the tip! Since your suggestion works, do you mind summarizing it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions always evaluate their arguments ***before*** invoking the function, leading expressions to be evaluated in the familiar "inside out" pattern:

```
(/ (inc 3) (dec 3))  ; orig
(/ 4 2)              ; args sent to `/` function
2                    ; final result
```

The purpose of a macro ***is to avoid evaluating the arguments*** before calling the function, leading to expressions being evaluated "outside in".  This allows one to compose macros as if each were a new language feature:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defmacro infix
  [[l op r]]
  `(~op ~l ~r))

(defmacro snoop
  [& forms]
  `(let [result# ~@forms]
     (do
       (println "snoop => " result#)
       result#)))

(dotest
  (spyx (infix (2 + 3)))
  (spyx (infix (5 - 3)))
  (newline)

  (snoop (+ 1 2))
  (snoop (infix (4 + 5)))
  (newline)

  (println :last
    (infix ((snoop 4) + (snoop 5)))))
```

with result

```
(infix (2 + 3)) => 5
(infix (5 - 3)) => 2

snoop =>  3
snoop =>  9

snoop =>  4
snoop =>  5
:last 9
```

So that final example has an intermediate stage that looks like:

```
(println :last
  (+ (snoop 4) (snoop 5)))
```

where can see that `infix` has been evaluated before the 2 `snoop` calls. This is exactly the strength of macros, and they would be useless without it.

You could maybe create a new macro that worked like:

```
(defmacro mmap
  [fns coll]
  `(let [comp-fn# (comp ~@fns)]
     (mapv comp-fn# ~coll)))

(mmap [inc inc inc] [1 2 3]) => [4 5 6]
```

---

While the above `mmap` works, it is really an abuse of the macro system, and might fail if you give it something other than compile-time constants.

A better alternative for basic functions is simple memoization of a normal function:

```
(def do-stuff
  (memoize ; will only execute on the first usage
    (fn
      [coll]
      (mapv #(* 2 %) (mapv inc coll)))))

(do-stuff [1 2 3 4]) => [4 6 8 10]
```

If you think even a single call at runtime is too much, I would suggest manually running the "macro-like" code in a pre-compilation step and saving the result in new "source file" that could then be compiled as usual (perhaps you are pre-computing a bunch of prime numbers, for example).

The upshot is that the macro system is intended ***only*** for manipulating code in order to add new language features.  Any other goal is better served using a different technique.

---

**Regarding `mapv`**

I also discovered `mapv` by accident and only after many months.

Be sure to bookmark [the Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) and always keep a browser tab open to it.  Study it regularly until you can remember each of the functions.  :)

Also be aware that some more obscure items *are not listed there*!

---

**Update:**

The "killer feature" of macros is to add new language features. In Java, et al, one can only add new libraries. As an example, spyx above is a macro very similar to the snoop example. For other examples see with-exception-default, vals->map, and it-> from [the Tupelo library](http://github.com/cloojure/tupelo). In fact, many "core" Clojure features like the for expression or the and & or logical operators are actually macros that any application program could write (or modify!).

Comment: A very exhaustive and educative answer! My actual code was meant to do something different than the (confusing) example. I wanted to compose a "map" macro and a "filter" macro, but reading your explanation I realized that a) even if I get it to work, it's really a fragile thing b) I was thinking in the wrong mindset: the evaluated macro is not what thought it would be, and in the end a compound macro would be a better solution. While I have a decent understanding of the compile-time/vs runtime thing, your answer helped me further it, which is why I'm accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: btw, I didn't knew there was a mapv. I should have known after writing ``(vec (map ...))`` so many times :p

Comment: Not sure what you are intending to compose with a "map macro" & "filter macro". If basic composition of `(map fa (filter fb coll))` or threading like `(->> coll (filter fb) (map fa))` isn't desirable, remember to also check out Clojure transducers.

Comment: My goal was to eliminate the overhead due to the use of frequent map/filter on very very short collections (while keeping a list-processing-like code) Would transducers help? I mean after creating one, are they virtually overhead-free upon use?

Comment: ... also, there was also pure academic curiosity, as I like to experiment with macros, and also I would really like to find a killer application of macros to show (off) to my java-centric collegues

Answer (score 1):

Macroexpansion works from the outermost form and is called repeatedly until a fixpoint is reached. That means that from your macro, you are given unexpanded code. This might be counter-untuitive if you expect it to work like functions, where arguments are evaluated before the function is called. With macro, nothing is expanded and nothing is evaluated, making it possible for your to interpret the underlying code as you wish.

But you are also free to call [macroexpand](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand) yourself from your macro, which will ensure that nested forms are expanded first. In your case, that means that with literal values, you will get data back, and you could process the macroexpanded value as-if it was given directly to your macro.

But note that this work only if the innermost call to your macro is given a literal value and produce a literal value back. In any case, a macro cannot know which value will be available at runtime. Usually people then try to call `eval` directly on forms, but this is a bad idea, because code depends on the runtime context, it makes no sense in general to evaluate code during macroexpansion/compilation that is supposed to be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry that I've not accepted it: I think they both deserved to be accepted. I appreciated of your answer that you provided me the exact solution to the problem I was asking, even though what I was asking was not the best idea (mmh... would have been morally bound to accept your answer then? :/ ). To partially compensate for it and, as a form of atonement, I'm going to browse your aswers to compensate the points. I'm quite sure I'll find plenty of them that deserve an upvote.

Comment: That's very nice of you but don't worry, I don't take those upvotes too seriously. Have a nice day.

Comment: well, broadening my horizons a bit didn't kill me :) btw after working a bit with Clojure I want more lisp, and reading some of your answers provided me with some tasty bits of what I can expect if I move to more traditional versions. Maybe if I want to enjoy lisp more I should move to CL and not use ELISP (I find the lack of namespaces very disturbing)... :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! CL is quite enjoyable. There is a twitch channel called Pushing pixels with Lisp which is quite interesting too. Cheers.